# how to get the OnClick event of Option menu button in Sherlock ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I am working on **Sherlock ActionBar** and using an Option button at right corner, near search icon. I am successful to generate the onClick event for SEARCH button but I am getting problems in onClick event of the option Button. 
Using the below code to add the buttons :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Search").setIcon(R.drawable.search_icon).setActionView(R.layout.action_search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Button").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_overflow_icon).setActionView(R.layout.action_button).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

And for click events :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            search = (EditText) item.getActionView();
            search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
            search.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(ActivityScreen.this, "hit it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   
    }
```

I have shown my requirement in the image attached below.
[image]

Comment: What problems exactly do you get?

Comment: @Ascorbin : onclick of the option I am not getting the onclick event.

Comment: your missing the `break;` statement from `case 2:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace** your **break;** statements in the Switch of onOptionsItemSelected to **return true;**

> **Addition to the answer**

```
final static int BUTTON_ID = 2;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, BUTTON_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.action_option_name);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.action_option);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case BUTTON_ID:
        Toast.makeText(this, "clicked on 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Note: I haven't added MenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.action_search). I tried to use the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11292843/1567588. But its not working. And i have set GroupId and OrderId to Menu.None

Comment: Problem is, I was not getting the Option button click event. I have replaced the break with return true, but still I am not getting the event for option button.

Comment: any answer for the requeired??

Comment: Wait, I am trying to recreate your issue.

Comment: is it a requirement to add menu items dynamically?. if not, then it would be straight forward to detect onClick event.

Comment: I am using Sherlock library for ActionBar, in which I have to add the menuItem at run time. No other option

Comment: Please check the Updated answer. Hope it helps somehow.