# How to add spinner in action bar menu items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

[image]I have searched a-lot about this but every one just changing the title into spinner.
I want some thing like if I add menu item and add this in its code.

```
    <item 
    android:id="@+id/spListOpt"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:title="@string/logout"
          />
```

Saw this on stack over flow but it doesn't show anything on action bar. 
Attaching picture for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom view for that,

**Example:**

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.spListOpt);
menuItemRefresh = MenuItem.setActionView(menuItem,R.layout.customview);
```

**Reference:**

[setActionView for MenuItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView(int))

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646150/android-actionbar-setactionview-layout-issue)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the spinner to the Actionbar the following way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate your menu layout
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.spListOpt);
    Spinner yourSpinnerName = (Spinner) menuItem.getActionView();
    ArrayList<String> spinnerStringArray = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add your data to your array
    spinnerStringArray.add("ItemOne");

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mSpinnerStringArray);
    yourSpinnerName.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    return true;
}
```